# How to convert a video to images, the image should be created when there's a change in the frame. OS - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I want to convert a video into the set of images. But I don't want the same images again and again. I want to know the command with which, it's possible to have the image only when there's a change in the frame. Operating system I'm using is ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some software to save only frames that are sufficiently different from the previous frame.  [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) may be able to do this if you can somehow get it to accept your video as input.

Comment: Is there any code/command to use with which it can make possible?